# Find exactly text which contain column's value in elasticsearch?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

```
id   text_1          text_2
1    おはよう         おはよ
2    こんにちは       ちわー
3    大丈夫           さよなら
4    でんわしたい     でんわしよう
```

I have DB same above.

I want to search with **input**: おはよう大丈夫？

**Result** will match: id = **1** and id = **3**.

Please help me how to search **multi_match** in **elasticsearch**?
Thanks you.

Comment: Result should be 1 and 3 right? Refer link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html

Comment: @swap0129: sorry, i just edited my post. Result expect are 1 and 3.

Comment: @swap0129: i use type => cross_fields but result match all data.

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /_search
{
 "query": {
   "multi_match" : {
     "query":    "おはよう大丈夫", 
     "fields": [ "text_1", "text_2" ],
     "type": "cross_fields",
     "analyzer": "standard"
   }
 }
}
```

Cross fields with same analyser.

Comment: i used above query, but result return all data. May be adding to another type or setting param into query?